# Get a nodeset that contains values from another nodeset XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm using XSLT1.0 and can't use any extensions. I have a node set and need to find all the elements in another node set that contain the values in the first and list them as related nodes.

The example below is a bit contrived, as the XML I'm working with is very large and contains confidential data so I made up some data.

In example in the following XML I am processing the sets. When I get to set_no 1 I find out that there are sub-sets 1,2 & 3. I then need to find *and list in sub_sec order*, all the book/chapter/section/sub_section/sub_sec elements, whose sec_no is in 1,2,3 (sets/set1/sub_set values)

So my result should be:

```
set1 
A
B
C
D
E
F
G

set2
A
B
C
D
G
```

In SQL, it would be an IN clause

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <sets>
        <set>
            <set_no>1</set_no>
            <sub_sets>
                <sub_set>1</sub_set>
                <sub_set>2</sub_set>
                <sub_set>3</sub_set>
            </sub_sets>
        </set>
        <set>
            <set_no>2</set_no>
            <sub_sets>
                <sub_set>1</sub_set>
                <sub_set>3</sub_set>
            </sub_sets>
        </set>
    </sets>
    <book>
        <chapter>
            <section>
                <sec_no>1</sec_no>
                <sub_section>
                    <sub_sec>A</sub_sec>
                    <sub_sec>B</sub_sec>
                    <sub_sec>C</sub_sec>
                    <sub_sec>D</sub_sec>
                    <sub_sec>G</sub_sec>
                </sub_section>
            </section>
            <section>
                <sec_no>2</sec_no>
                <sub_section>
                    <sub_sec>E</sub_sec>
                    <sub_sec>F</sub_sec>
                </sub_section>
            </section>
        </chapter>
    </book>
</root>
```

I'm stuck on how to do this in XSLT1.0

The way I was doing it was iterating over sets and for each set then iterating over sections. This worked until the requirement changed to sort by sub_sec (so sort over multiple sections

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>


    <xsl:template match="root">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="sets/set">
                    <xsl:variable name="curr_set" select="set_no"/> 
                    Set: <xsl:value-of select="$curr_set"/>
                    <br/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="sub_sets/sub_set">
                        <xsl:variable name="curr_sub_set" select="node()"/> 
                        <!--Curr-Sub-Set: <xsl:value-of select="$curr_sub_set"/><br/>-->
                        <xsl:for-each select="/root/book/chapter/section[sec_no=$curr_sub_set]/sub_section/sub_sec">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <br/><br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What does *in sub_sec order* mean? Why does `G` come after `E` and `F` in your expected output?

Comment: @michael.hor257k. Not sure how else to explain it. Output should be a list of all sub_sec elements sorted in alphabetical order

Comment: Ah! That's something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="sets/set">
                Set: <xsl:value-of select="set_no"/>
                <br/>
                <xsl:for-each select="/root/book/chapter/section[sec_no=current()/sub_sets/sub_set]/sub_section/sub_sec">
                    <xsl:sort select="."/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />                    
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

This produces:

```
Set: 1<br>A<br>B<br>C<br>D<br>E<br>F<br>G<br>
Set: 2<br>A<br>B<br>C<br>D<br>G<br>
```

where the output is ordered as you requested.

In the predicate expression `[sec_no=current()/sub_sets/sub_set]`, current() is bound to the *set* being evaluated, and therefore `current()/sub_sets/sub_set` gets the list of *sub_set* values in the current *set*.  The predicate will be true when the *sec_no* is in this list.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks a lot. Can't believe that I didn't know about that

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is best solved using a [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="sub_sec-by-sec_no" match="sub_sec" use="ancestor::section/sec_no" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="sets/set">
                Set: <xsl:value-of select="set_no"/>
                <br/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('sub_sec-by-sec_no', sub_sets/sub_set)">
                    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <br/><br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```